# Scipy spectrogram of .wav file looks violet

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, audio-processing, spectrogram

```py
import os
import scipy.io
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.signal import spectrogram, get_window

dataset_path = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'shared', 'data', 'assignment_1')
wavedata = os.path.join(dataset_path, 'example.wav')
   
fs, audio_buffer = scipy.io.wavfile.read(wavedata)

a = np.array(audio_buffer)


window = get_window('hann', frame_size)  # we will us a Hann window for the DFTs
    
freqs, times, spec = scipy.signal.spectrogram(audio_buffer, fs, window='hann')

plt.pcolormesh(times, freqs, spec)
np.log(spec)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

I tried to make a spectrogram. The problem is that it is almost completely violet.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You may want to plot the histogram of the spectrogram values, then you can see what the range of values present are.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456419/reproduce-sox-spectrogram-in-scipy/

Comment: What's the point of your line `np.log(spec)`?

Comment: @tom10 actually that was an attempt to make logarithmic spectrogram which failed. but now I figured out

Comment: Great. Yes, the `np.log(spec)` seemed to be aiming at the right approach, but it was so just hanging there that I didn't know what you knew and didn't, and I therefore didn't quite see how to post an answer. In general, if you say things like, "the graph is all purple, and I thought `np.log(spec)` would fix that but it doesn't" it would be much easier to answer your questions.