# How to obtain a clear spectrograph of an oversampled sinusoid with increasing frequency?

Tags: python, scipy, spectrogram, frequency-analysis

Consider following example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as scp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#make signal
deltat = 1e-4
t = np.linspace(0,300000,300001) * deltat
y = np.exp(-t/10)*np.sin(np.pi * (t/4)**2)

#plot signal
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.show()

#calculate spectrogram
f, t, Sxx = scp.signal.spectrogram(y, 1/deltat)

#plot spectrogram
plt.figure(2)
plt.clf()
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylim([0, 100])
plt.show()
```

A sine with increasing frequency and decreasing amplitude is created and its spectrogram is plotted. Note that the sine is oversampled (it represents a measurement at fixed time step `deltat`).

[image]

The spectrogram should be an increasing line (increasing frequency) of decreasing color (decreasing amplitude). How can I obtain the correct spectrogram?

- Trying to include the `nperseg` and `noverlap` keywords in the [`spectrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) function does only give me other wrong spectrograms.
- Should I use an alternative Python function instead of `spectrogram`? **Update:** I have also tried using [`librosa.stft`](http://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html) without success.
- Is the problem related to the oversampling?

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the docstring of [`scipy.signal.chirp`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html) (scroll down to the bottom to see the examples that use `spectrogram`).  Also, my [chapter on linear filters with SciPy](https://warrenweckesser.github.io/papers/weckesser-scipy-linear-filters.pdf) (for the PyData book that never was) has some notes on using `spectrogram` starting on page 4.

Comment: Another example that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456419/reproduce-sox-spectrogram-in-scipy